# LM339 comparator not working properly in the defined window

Tags: flipflop, comparator

I have designed a circuit that uses an [LM2901](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm2901) comparator which is used for a window in which I should get a signal. I have set two limits for the comparator: 7.7 to 8.8 V for the lower limit, and 11.3 to 12.7 V for the upper limit. When I apply the input signal, I should get an output when the signal lies between these limits.

The problem I am encountering is that while the lower limit is working as designed, the upper limit seems to have a tolerance; it works in the range from 11.3 to 12.2 V and not the 12.7 V that is was designed for. I am not sure exactly what is wrong with it.

Vin1: 8.8 V
Vin2: 7.7 V
Vin3: 12.7 V
Vin4: 11.3 V
Hall sensor: Input signal varying from 5 to 16 V.

The input signal is from a Hall sensor, and the outputs Ul_A and Uh_B go to a SR flip-flop which controls a couple of optocouplers.

[image]

I've tried changing the pull-up resistors R300 and R301 from 10 kΩ to 100 kΩ, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You don't need those 2 diodes on the outputs of the LM339, inside is a NPN transistor (on the  output) en the emitter is tied to ground, so the diodes are redundant, you need to see the outputs of LM339 and LM393 as a NPN inverter setup, hence the needed resistor on the outputs.

Comment: I didn't realise the LM339 had the AND gate operation when the outputs are connected. It was after you and @Simon Finch pointed this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum input voltage you can apply to these LM339/LM2901 devices is 1.5V *less* than the positive supply, which is described by the \$V_{ICR}\$ parameter on page 12 of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2901.pdf) you linked to.

In your case, if Vcc is 13V, this would be \$13V - 1.5V = +11.5V\$.

It surprises me that the lower range comparator works without issues when the input rises too far, but the takeaway is that the behaviour of the comparators is not guaranteed, or even defined, if any input falls outside the range {GND...Vcc-1.5}.

Also, these comparators have open-collector outputs, meaning that you do not need diodes D300, D301, D302 and D303 to diode-AND; you may literally join the comparator outputs together directly, to perform the AND function.

***Edit: Proposed Solution***

If you wish to avoid having to provide a greater supply potential Vcc, you can simply scale all the input voltages by the same factor, (say, one half) using potential dividers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUEjXl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now all the voltages presented at the comparator inputs lie well within the common mode input voltage range of the device, and it will behave as you expected.

Comment: with the VICR being +11.5V in this case, would this be the reason as to why the upper window only works from 11.3V to ~12.1V-12.2V and not till the designed 12.7V?

Comment: If I was to supply the comparator with 24V instead of the 13V, would it work in this case? sorry if these questions are too trivial.

Comment: @EmeraldMonk The questions are fine, don't worry. Yes, a supply of 24V would solve your problem, if I am correct in my response above. A supply of 12.7V + 1.5V = 14.2V would be OK, but only just. In practice you must provide a supply equal to or greater than 1.5V above the greatest voltage you *ever* expect to see at any input (for the LM339).

Comment: @EmeraldMonk I will propose a solution (as an addendum to my answer) that doesn't require a larger supply, if you can wait a few minutes.

Comment: I connected the Vcc of the comparator to a 24V input as I found it easier to do rather than solder a bunch of resistor to get the voltage divider. The comparator started to work as intended. Your input is much appreciated.